# Java ping pong game (form youtube tutorial), paddles doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

I made a ping pong game in Java but the paddles doesn't work, and I can't figure out the problem.

Main class: in the main class I give the thread and run the program:

```
package pingpong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PingPong extends JFrame {

    int Gwidth=400,Gheight=300;
    Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(Gwidth,Gheight);
     //double Buffering
    Image dbImage;
    Graphics dbg;
    //ball objects 
    static Ball b = new Ball(193,143);
    //constructor
    public PingPong() {
        this.setTitle("ping pong Game");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(screenSize);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);

    }
   public void draw(Graphics g) {
      b.draw(g);
      b.p1.draw(g);
      b.p2.draw(g);

      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.drawString(""+b.p1Score,15,50);
      g.drawString(""+b.p2Score,370,50);

      repaint();
    }
       //event listining class
        public class AL extends KeyAdapter {        //key buildings

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
           b.p1.keyPressed( e);
           b.p2.keyPressed( e);   
        }
        public void keyRealesed(KeyEvent e){
            b.p1.keyReleased( e);
            b.p2.keyReleased( e);
        }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PingPong pp = new PingPong();
        //create and start threads
        Thread ball=new Thread(b);
        ball.start();
        Thread p1=new Thread(b.p1);
        Thread p2= new Thread(b.p2); 
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
    }

}
```

this is my ball class:

```
    package pingpong;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.Random;


    public class Ball implements Runnable{
        //global variables
        int x,y,XDir,YDir;

        //score
        int p1Score,p2Score;

      Paddle p1=new Paddle(15 , 140, 1);
      Paddle p2=new Paddle(370, 140 ,2 );

        Rectangle ball;

        public Ball(int x,int y){
            p1Score=p2Score=0;
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            //randomly moving the ball
            Random r=new Random();
             int rDir = r.nextInt(1);
            if (rDir == 0) {
                rDir--;
            }setXDir(rDir);
            int yrDir = r.nextInt(1);
            if (yrDir == 0) {
                yrDir--;
            }setYDir(yrDir);
             //create 'ball'
            ball = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y,7, 7);
        }
         public void collision(){
            if(ball.intersects(p1.paddle)){
                setXDir(+1);}
            if(ball.intersects(p2.paddle)){
                setXDir(-1);}
        }
        public void draw(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillRect(ball.x,ball.y,ball.width,ball.height);
        }
        public void move(){
            collision();
            ball.x +=XDir;
            ball.y +=YDir;
            //bounce the ball when edge is detected 
            if(ball.x<0){

                setXDir(+1);
                //add to score
                p1Score++; //? 
            }
            if(ball.x>=385){
                setXDir(-1);
                //add to score
                p2Score++; //?
            }
            if(ball.y<=15) 
                setYDir(+1);
            if(ball.y>=270)
                setYDir(-1);
        }

        public void setXDir(int xdir){
            XDir=xdir;
        }
        public void setYDir(int ydir){
            YDir=ydir;
        }








        public void run(){
            try{
                while(true){
                    move();
                    Thread.sleep(4);
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("sorry"+e.getMessage());}
        }
    }

and there is my paddle class :


package pingpong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Paddle implements Runnable {

    int x, y, yDir, id;

    Rectangle paddle;

    public Paddle(int x, int y, int id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
        paddle = new Rectangle(x, y, 15, 50);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (id) {
            default:
                System.out.println("please enter a valid id");
                break;
            case 1:
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
                    setYDir(-1);
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
                    setYDir(+1);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_W) {
                    setYDir(-1);
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S) {
                    setYDir(+1);
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (id) {
            default:
                System.out.println("please enter a valid id");
                break;
            case 1:
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
                    setYDir(0);
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
                    setYDir(0);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_W) {
                    setYDir(0);
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S) {
                    setYDir(0);
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        switch (id) {
            default:
                System.out.println("please enter a valid id");
                break;
            case 2:
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                //draw paddle #1
                g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
                break;
            case 1:
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                // draw paddle #2
                g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
                break;
        }

    }

    public void setYDir(int ydir) {
        yDir = ydir;
    }

    public void move() {
        paddle.x += yDir;
        if (paddle.y <= 15) {
            paddle.y = 15;
        }
        if (paddle.y >= 250) {
            paddle.y = 250;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                move();
                Thread.sleep(6);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("try again" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I personally think I have a problem in the paddle but I can't figure it out.

Comment: "Doesn't work": please describe the desired behaviour and what happens instead.

Comment: `paddle.x += yDir;` doesn't look correct.

Comment: Don't override `paint` of top level containers, you're reinventing a wheel which already has a simple solution. Instead of extending from `JFrame`, extend from `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method instead, you will get double buffering free...and you won't risk painting under the frame borders. `KeyListener` is a poor choice for handling key events, instead you should use the [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) api

Comment: You are also going to need to synchronise access to the paddle and balls' member variables, since you don't have guaranteed visibility of updates from other threads. (Or use AtomicInteger instead of int)

Comment: Swing is also NOT thread safe and you should avoid updating the UI or something the UI is relying on from outside the EDT...over all, not a very good tutorial...

Comment: can you suggest me a good tutorial @MadProgrammer , i really appreciate it

Comment: @AndyTurner my problem is the paddles should go up and down when pressed w,s for player 1 and ,up and down arrows for player 2

Comment: @Pouyakharrazi That is your desired behaviour. Please describe what happens instead.

Comment: @AndyTurner the paddles doesn't work when i press the buttons

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question a bit. It seems a good question, only a bit long. If you can get a smaller piece of code that illustrates the problem, that would really help. Good luck, hope you'll be able to get it working!

Comment: Thanks you @S.L.Barth for your help , problem is in main class and paddle class , ball class is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving your paddle in Y axis (inside `move`, this looks wrong:

```
    paddle.x += yDir;
```

Should be

```
    paddle.y += yDir;
```

Comment: i found the problem it , i didn't add Keylistener to my PingPong class